# TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' error

Tags: python, list, pygame

I have a list to store the X and Y of bullets in my game, and when spacebar is pushed, it adds an x and y to the list, and then it should call both values and draw them. i know i need to delete them after they leave the screen, but atm when i hit space this error pops up

```
   TypeError:'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

here's my code:

```
#start system
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import*
pygame.init()
fps=50
Clock=pygame.time.Clock()#use fps as system time
#set up a list of STUFF
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN = ( 0, 100, 0)
RED   = ( 100, 0, 0)
YELLOW= (255,255,0)
ORANGE= (255,165,0)
screensizex=800
screensizey=600
bullets=[]
screenarea=pygame.display.set_mode((screensizex,screensizey))
pygame.display.set_caption("space invaders")
player_x=250
# end of variable init, begin main loop!
while 1==1:
    #key roster
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_d and player_x<screensizex-25:
                player_x+=25
            if event.key==K_a:
                player_x-=25
            if event.key==K_SPACE:
                bullets.insert(player_x,665)
    #drawing to screen             
    screenarea.fill(WHITE)
    for bullet in bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(screenarea,ORANGE,Rect(bullet[0],bullet[1],5,10))
    pygame.draw.rect(screenarea,GREEN,(0,screensizey-100,screensizex,100))
    pygame.draw.rect(screenarea,RED,(player_x,screensizey-125,25,25))
    pygame.display.update()
    Clock.tick(fps)
```

can you help me out? how do i call both values?

Comment: when you try `bullet[0]` it will raise this exception, as bullet is an `int` object, and trying to index it will give the exception you see (with python3, it is `'int' object is not subscriptable` instead).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you meant to put tuples into your list, so this:

```
bullets.insert(player_x,665)
```

Should be:

```
bullets.append((player_x,665))
```

Comment: this threw up another error code because bullets.insert takes one arguement?

Comment: @user3423925 maybe what you actually want is `bullets.append(...)` ?

Comment: these seem to be rather beginner problems, so I would suggest you go read through e.g. http://www.diveintopython.net/, free and a great intro to all that is basic python.

Comment: normally i dont have these kind of problems but i've struggled with this for hours. i get all different kinds of error codes, and i've tried loads of different combinations. ill have a read thanks :)